# How to make this code to use for many inputs

Tags: javascript

I need this replacer to use it for many inputs with one selector. Now I use different selectors and same code with just selectors differ

```js
var en = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>?~&";
var ru = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ёЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,Ё?";
var alphabet = {};

for (var i = 0; i < en.length; i++) {
  alphabet[en[i]] = ru[i];
}

// console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabet));

var InputReciever = document.getElementById("InputReciever");
InputReciever.addEventListener("input", function() {
  InputReciever.innerHTML = toRussianStr(this.value);
});

function toRussianStr(str) {
  return str.replace(/\S/g, function(match) {
    return alphabet[match] || match;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="form__option">
  <input placeholder="Город получателя" id="InputReciever" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Город получателя'" onkeydown="InputReciever.value=toRussianStr(InputReciever.value)" onchange="InputReciever.value=toRussianStr(InputReciever.value)"
    type="text" class="InputReciever field" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

Comment: The id attribute cannot have spaces. Use dashes or underscores instead.

Comment: first step solved =)